# A few questions about the apt rdepends and apt-cache rdepends commands?

Tags: linux, apt

I ran the command `apt-cache rdepends gnome-session-bin` and got the following output:

```
gnome-session-bin
Reverse Depends:
  unity-session
  gnome-shell-extensions
  gnome-session-flashback
  budgie-core
 |software-properties-gtk
  gdm3
  unity-session
  gnome-session-flashback
  unity-session
  unity-session
  unity-control-center
  session-shortcuts
  phosh-core
  phosh
  openbox-gnome-session
  gnome-shell-extensions
  gnome-startup-applications
  gnome-session
  gnome-session
  gnome-session
  gnome-session
  budgie-core
  ubuntu-session
  ubuntu-session
 |software-properties-gtk
  nautilus-share
  gnome-startup-applications
  gnome-startup-applications
  gnome-session-common
  gnome-session-common
  gdm3
```

I learned on the Internet that if a package name is preceded by a vertical bar `|`, it means that the package is an alternative. And all the packages that are below it (up to the next package, before the name of which there is a vertical bar), these are already packages that depend on it, and not on the one I specified in the command. This is true? If so, why is it that when I run the command without `-cache`: `apt rdepends gnome-session-bin`, packages that have a vertical bar in front of their names are marked as Recommends?

```
gnome-session-bin
Reverse Depends:
  Breaks: unity-session (<< 3.37.0-2ubuntu1~)
  Depends: gnome-shell-extensions (>= 3.8)
  Depends: gnome-session-flashback (>= 3.33.92)
  Depends: budgie-core
 |Recommends: software-properties-gtk
  Depends: gdm3 (>= 3.37.0)
  Replaces: unity-session (<< 3.37.0-2ubuntu1~)
  Depends: gnome-session-flashback (>= 3.33.92)
  Depends: unity-session (>= 42.0-1ubuntu2)
  Depends: unity-session (<< 43~)
  Recommends: unity-control-center
  Depends: session-shortcuts
  Depends: phosh-core
  Recommends: phosh
  Depends: openbox-gnome-session
  Depends: gnome-shell-extensions (>= 3.8)
  Breaks: gnome-startup-applications (<< 3.28.0-0ubuntu4~)
  Replaces: gnome-session (<< 3.37.0-2~)
  Breaks: gnome-session (<< 3.37.0-2~)
  Depends: gnome-session (>= 42.0-1ubuntu2)
  Depends: gnome-session (<< 43~)
  Depends: budgie-core
  Depends: ubuntu-session (>= 42.0-1ubuntu2)
  Depends: ubuntu-session (<< 43~)
 |Recommends: software-properties-gtk
  Depends: nautilus-share
  Replaces: gnome-startup-applications (<< 3.28.0-0ubuntu4~)
  Depends: gnome-startup-applications (>= 42.0-1ubuntu2)
  Breaks: gnome-session-common (<< 3.37.0-2~)
  Replaces: gnome-session-common (<< 3.37.0-2~)
  Depends: gdm3 (>= 3.37.0)
```

Recommends and Provides are two different things.

And another question. Is it possible to make the output of the `apt-cache rdepends gnome-session-bin` command have Breaks, Recommends, Depends... flags and versions, just like the command without `-cache`: `apt rdepends gnome-session-bin`?